# can not find the body tag in omegle.com using js console

Tags: jquery, html

> document.getElementsByTagName("body")

on executing the above line on omegle.com using a javascript console in mozilla i am getting an empty array why is that so ? while on viewing the page source the body tag seems to be there at its place .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it doesn't actually have a `<body>` element, the browser's just attempting to render it anyway, you can see the page source:

```
    </head>
    <!-- Yes, I'm using frames as a load balancing measure. Yes, I know
         this is horrible, insane, absurd, ridiculous, stupid, and
         broken. It's just a temporary stop-gap measure, though. -->
    <frameset cols="100%">
        <frame src="http://bajor.omegle.com/">
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Note that a `<frameset>` element should *not* be used with a `<body>`, so this is [correct usage](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://omegle.com/&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: ohh .. i don't know why the chore was displaying the body tag doing a view page source. thanks anyway

Comment: @Bunny - you were probably viewing the source of the frame that's displayed, not the parent page, which is what your console's looking at.